# Log4J print process id and thread id in java and unix

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am setting up log4j config to print the process id from java code

```
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d pid:[%pid] %-5p %c{-2} %x - %m%n
```

I attempting to use pid:[%pid] for the purpose. But, when I deployed this in our unix server,
I get the output like this -> pid:[INFOid] and not process id.

I did refer [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout). it seems %pid is the way to go, but it doesnt seem to work. What am i doing wrong?

a sample full output log line looks like below

```
2023-05-12 09:17:18,513 pid:[INFOid] INFO  com.test.my.class  - Attempting publish ...
```

Comment: The documentation you are referencing is for Log4j 2.x, but you are using Log4j 1.x.